# Why does implicit UNNEST not work as the docs say it should?

Tags: google-bigquery

According to the [BigQuery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#unnest):

> In implicit unnesting, array_path must resolve to an ARRAY and the UNNEST keyword is optional.
>
> Example:
>
> `SELECT * FROM mytable.struct_typed_column.array_typed_field1;`

Yet when I try this on a real appengine log exported via StackDriver:

```
SELECT *
FROM log_stream.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20160928.protoPayload.line
```

I get the error:

> Invalid table name: log_stream.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20160928:protoPayload.line

To clarify what I am trying to accomplish, in case that helps, this query returns rows that I'm trying to UNNEST:

```
SELECT protoPayload.line
FROM log_stream.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20160928
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(protoPayload.line) > 0
LIMIT 10
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed an (internal) bug against our documentation to clarify this section based on your feedback so hopefully we can have it fixed soon. [This section](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql#removing_repetition_with_flatten) of the migration guide is a little more helpful in the meantime.

Assuming that `line` repeats this does what you want:

```
SELECT line
FROM log_stream.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20160928 AS t,
  t.protoPayload.line AS line
LIMIT 10;
```

Or, if the `protoPayload` repeats, this does:

```
SELECT protoPayload.line
FROM log_stream.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20160928 AS t,
  t.protoPayload AS protoPayload
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: so, now -  this statement in doc - `and the UNNEST keyword is optional` - makes sense

Comment: It would be better if the examples in that section were actually valid queries, too--it's hard to interpret what it means if you can't easily apply the contents to some sample data.

Comment: totally agree. there is definitelly a room for these docs' improvements

Comment: If you have other suggestions, please feel free to submit items on our issue tracker too: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list. I wrote one piece of our docs, namely the migration guide, but I try to work closely with our tech writers to make sure everything else is in good shape as well :) Thanks!